# Laravel 4 hasOne / belongsTo relationship

Tags: php, foreign-keys, laravel, laravel-4

Get the feeling I'm being particularly dumb here but it's doing my nut in.

I have a `candidate` table with the `country_id` field as a foreign key to the countries table.  A candidate has one linked country.

The Candidate model has a relationship defined as:

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Country', 'country_id');
}
```

And the Country model has the following:

```
public function candidate()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Candidate');
}
```

On my listing page I'm using `Candidate::with('country')->paginate(5)` to provide a list of the Candidates on screen.  When I come to display the country I use:

```
$candidate->country->country
```

But this returns the error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I can, however, use

```
$candidate->country['country']
```

Using `var_dump` on `$candidate->country` suggests that an object is returned, so why can't I access it as an object?

**EDIT:**

The candidates controller is namespaced to admin as follows:

```
namespace App\Controllers\Admin;
```

and as part of the declarations in the controller I have:

```
use App\Models\Candidate, App\Models\Manufacturer, App\Models\Make, App\Models\Country;
```

Each model is namespaced with

```
namespace App\Models
```

Have I even got the relationship set up correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Does your Country table have a column named country as well? Could you please post the SQL Table structure as well?

Comment: Your error: > Trying to get property of non-object Is thrown by Eloquent when there is no row with proper ID in table connected by `hasOne()` function.

Comment: Could you post the result of said `var_dump` if this is still an issue?