# Laravel 4: How to access data from belongsTo() relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, relationships

```
// models:
class Hometype extends Eloquent {
    public function development() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Development');
    }
}

class Development extends Eloquent {
    public function hometypes() {
        return $this->hasMany('Hometype', 'dev_id');
    }
}
```

with that, I can do:

```
// controller:
$development = Development::where('stuff')->first();
// view:
@foreach ($development->hometypes as $hometype)
    {{ $hometype->stuff }}
@endforeach
```

which is perfectly lovely.

but I can't seem to do:

```
// controller:
$hometype = Hometype::where('stuff')->first();
// view:
{{ $hometype->development->stuff }} // <- fails
```

**How do I access a field on the parent Development model from within $hometype?**

I'm resorting to:

```
'development' => Development::find($hometype->dev_id),
```

which seems silly.

Possible duplicate of: [Laravel 4 - Can't retrieve data in a one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924514/laravel-4-cant-retrieve-data-in-a-one-to-many-relationship), but I'm not camelCasing...

Also similar to: [Laravel 4 hasOne / belongsTo relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014646/laravel-4-hasone-belongsto-relationship)  (no answers here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see, there might be two problems:

1. The foreign key in Hometype is wrong (if you're using a different column name than "column"_id then you have to specify it)
2. You might be fetching a Hometype record whose development row doesn't exist

Comment: Curse myself, simple as that.   Reason number one.

`return $this->belongsTo('Development', 'dev_id');`

and everything works as I intended. Didn't realize you need to specify custom foreign keys on **both** models.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Accessing data and methods between hasMany and belongsTo
First get required models and then loop through

These are the model:

```
class ExpenseCategory extends Model
  public function expense_transactions()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\ExpenseTransaction');
  }


  class ExpenseTransaction extends Model
      public function expense_category()
      {  
          return $this->belongsTo('App\ExpenseCategory');
      }
```

Schema for the above model:

```
Schema::create('expense_transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('expense_category_id')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedInteger('day_sheet_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('expense_title')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedInteger('amount');
    $table->timestamps();

$table->foreign('expense_category_id')
      ->references('id')->on('expense_categories')
      ->onDelete('cascade');

$table->foreign('day_sheet_id')
      ->references('id')->on('day_sheets')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Schema for category:

```
Schema::create('expense_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();  
    });
```

find only expense transactions for day sheet id in model

```
$expenseTransactions = ExpenseTransaction::where('day_sheet_id', $id)->get();
```

show their category name
access in blade:
in a foreach loop

```
@foreach($expense_transactions as $expense_transaction)
{{ $expense_transaction->expense_category->name  }}
```